# Failure to install R package RcppArmadillo on Arch

Tags: r, rcpp, intel-mkl

I am trying to install the R package `RcppArmadillo` on Arch. However, I run into issues during compilation:

```
* installing *source* package ‘RcppArmadillo’ ...
** package ‘RcppArmadillo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C++... yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++17 accepts -g... yes
checking for g++ -std=gnu++17 option to enable C++11 features... none needed
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -std=gnu++17 -E
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C++... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++17 accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for g++ -std=gnu++17 option to enable C++11 features... (cached) none needed
checking whether we have a suitable tempdir... /tmp
checking whether R CMD SHLIB can already compile programs using OpenMP... yes
checking LAPACK_LIBS... system LAPACK found
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating inst/include/RcppArmadillo/config/RcppArmadilloConfigGenerated.h
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
using C++ compiler: ‘g++ (GCC) 13.2.1 20230801’
g++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/include/R/" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I'/home/thesixmax/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fopenmp -fpic  -m64 -ffat-lto-objects -I/opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2023.1.0/include -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fno-plt -fexceptions         -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security         -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS  -c RcppArmadillo.cpp -o RcppArmadillo.o
g++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/include/R/" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I'/home/thesixmax/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fopenmp -fpic  -m64 -ffat-lto-objects -I/opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2023.1.0/include -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fno-plt -fexceptions         -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security         -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/include/R/" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I'/home/thesixmax/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fopenmp -fpic  -m64 -ffat-lto-objects -I/opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2023.1.0/include -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fno-plt -fexceptions         -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security         -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS  -c fastLm.cpp -o fastLm.o
g++ -std=gnu++17 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -o RcppArmadillo.so RcppArmadillo.o RcppExports.o fastLm.o -fopenmp -L/opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2023.1.0/lib/intel64 -Wl,--no-as-needed -lmkl_gf_lp64 -lmkl_gnu_thread -lmkl_core -lgomp -lpthread -lm -ldl -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmkl_gf_lp64: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmkl_gnu_thread: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmkl_core: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/usr/share/R//make/shlib.mk:10: RcppArmadillo.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppArmadillo’
* removing ‘/home/thesixmax/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/RcppArmadillo’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RcppArmadillo’ had non-zero exit status
```

It appears to be related to the fact that I am running `r-mkl`. However, I am not sure why R would not recognise the files listed, since the relevant directory does contain symlinks to the files:

```
[thesixmax@thesixmax-pc ~]$ ls /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2023.2.0/lib/intel64/
libmkl_avx2.so.2                  libmkl_blacs_openmpi_lp64.so    libmkl_gf_ilp64.so.2     libmkl_intel_thread.a     libmkl_scalapack_ilp64.so    libmkl_tbb_thread.so.2
libmkl_avx512.so.2                libmkl_blacs_openmpi_lp64.so.2  libmkl_gf_lp64.a         libmkl_intel_thread.so    libmkl_scalapack_ilp64.so.2  libmkl_vml_avx2.so.2
libmkl_avx.so.2                   libmkl_blas95_ilp64.a           libmkl_gf_lp64.so        libmkl_intel_thread.so.2  libmkl_scalapack_lp64.a      libmkl_vml_avx512.so.2
libmkl_blacs_intelmpi_ilp64.a     libmkl_blas95_lp64.a            libmkl_gf_lp64.so.2      libmkl_lapack95_ilp64.a   libmkl_scalapack_lp64.so     libmkl_vml_avx.so.2
libmkl_blacs_intelmpi_ilp64.so    libmkl_cdft_core.a              libmkl_gnu_thread.a      libmkl_lapack95_lp64.a    libmkl_scalapack_lp64.so.2   libmkl_vml_cmpt.so.2
libmkl_blacs_intelmpi_ilp64.so.2  libmkl_cdft_core.so             libmkl_gnu_thread.so     libmkl_mc3.so.2           libmkl_sequential.a          libmkl_vml_def.so.2
libmkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.a      libmkl_cdft_core.so.2           libmkl_gnu_thread.so.2   libmkl_mc.so.2            libmkl_sequential.so         libmkl_vml_mc3.so.2
libmkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.so     libmkl_core.a                   libmkl_intel_ilp64.a     libmkl_pgi_thread.a       libmkl_sequential.so.2       libmkl_vml_mc.so.2
libmkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.so.2   libmkl_core.so                  libmkl_intel_ilp64.so    libmkl_pgi_thread.so      libmkl_sycl.a                locale
libmkl_blacs_openmpi_ilp64.a      libmkl_core.so.2                libmkl_intel_ilp64.so.2  libmkl_pgi_thread.so.2    libmkl_sycl.so
libmkl_blacs_openmpi_ilp64.so     libmkl_def.so.2                 libmkl_intel_lp64.a      libmkl_rt.so              libmkl_sycl.so.3
libmkl_blacs_openmpi_ilp64.so.2   libmkl_gf_ilp64.a               libmkl_intel_lp64.so     libmkl_rt.so.2            libmkl_tbb_thread.a
libmkl_blacs_openmpi_lp64.a       libmkl_gf_ilp64.so              libmkl_intel_lp64.so.2   libmkl_scalapack_ilp64.a  libmkl_tbb_thread.so
```

The same error appears when trying to install `r-rcpparmadillo` from AUR. I have had no problems otherwise with `r-mkl`, and `Rcpp` compiles without any issues. I could try to compile on the non-MKL version of R, but wanted to explore if there is an easy solution to this in the first place. Any suggestions?

Comment: Recall that RcppArmadillo just expands `$(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)` so this is between you, your R installation, and your blas/lapack choices. I have had no issues with MKL in the past on my box (see old repo [mkl2deb](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/mkl4deb) I did as a service, these days you get MKL directly from inside Debian and Ubuntu.